# UnboundLocalError when running splinter browser

Tags: python, splinter

I get the following error:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment`

When I try to use splinter browser as:

```
gekoExe_path = {'executable_path': <gekodriver path>}
browser= Browser('firefox', **gekoExe_path, headless= False)
```

I'm using splinter version: '0.13.0'

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the splinter version to 0.11.0

**If you are using LINUX**
move the geckodriver executable file to /usr/bin/

**If Windows**
add the directory path of the geckodriver and add it to system variable "PATH"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by installing the development version found [here](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html),
and adding the gekodriver executable to PATH